# How two decile bin continuous variables?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-analysis, data-manipulation

I am trying to decile my data into equal bins and summarise it to see if there are any existing patterns with respect to the Dependent Variable. While summarising the data, I also want to see the lower bound and the upper bound of a variable for each decile.

I have written the below code in R-

```
    telecom_final_Analyse<-read.csv("sampletelecomfinal.csv")
    col_name_final<-colnames(telecom_final_Analyse)

    Variable_profile<-vector("list",79) #I have 79 variables

    names(Variable_profile)<-col_name_final


    for (j in 1:79) {
      if(class(telecom_final_Analyse[,col_name_final[j]])=="numeric" || class(telecom_final_Analyse[,col_name_final[j]])=="integer"){

        telecom_final_Analyse%>%mutate(dec=ntile(telecom_final_Analyse[,col_name_final[j]],10))->telecom_final_Analyse

        z<-as.name(col_name_final[j])

        telecom_final_Analyse%>%group_by(dec)%>%summarise(n=sum(churn),N=n(),churn_percentage=n/N,greaterthan = min(z,na.rm=TRUE),lessthan=max(z,na.rm=TRUE))->Variable_profile[[col_name_final[j]]]

      }
      else{
        x<-as.name(col_name_final[j])
        telecom_final_Analyse%>%group_by_(x)%>%summarise(n=sum(churn),N=n(),churn_percentage=n/N)->Variable_profile[[col_name_final[j]]]

      }
    }
```

I am getting the following error - ***Error in min(z, na.rm = TRUE) : invalid 'type' (symbol) of argument***

**The following is the code I used for one variable to get the desired output** In the same way I want to get output for all integer/numeric variables in the dataset

```
telecom_final_Analyse%>%mutate(dec=ntile(telecom_final_Analyse$eqpdays ,10))->telecom_final_Analyse

telecom_final_Analyse%>%group_by(dec)%>%summarise(n=sum(churn),N=n(),churn_percentage=n/N,greaterthan=min(eqpdays,na.rm=TRUE),lessthan=max(eqpdays,na.rm=TRUE))
```

[I am able to do it manually for 1 variable, this is the output I got. The same way I want for my other continuous variables as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B5Xb.png)

Comment: Hi Ajay, thanks for your question and a warm welcome to the StackOverflow community. I'm sure I can help you with your question. However, please consider that you hope to get an answer from someone who spends his/her free time to answer your question. On StackOverflow, it's good practice as an asker to provide a 
reproducible example (sometimes called reprex) https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example A reprex helps others to understand your problem and also helps folks with similar questions to quickly decide whether this particular thread is useful or not.

Comment: `z` is a variable of type symbol. It is not numeric so you cannot compute its mean. Give us some data (10 - 20 cases with 3 - 5 variables) and tell us what you want in the end. I will be very surprised if you need a loop to do this.

Comment: @dcarlson thanks for the response. Please use the sample dataset from - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vVCzKz7N0_jecTwRlz1Jyjdi4-7XLLgo/view?usp=sharing I want to bin all the continuous variables into 10 deciles and group them by decile and summarise to see no.of rows, sum of churn (a variable in data), minimum & maximum values of each variable for each decile. Please refer the image, I did it for one variable and I want to get same kind of output for all numeric/integer variables

Answer (score 0):

I've not run this (no reprex) but you can extent your code for the single variable with mutate_if(is.numeric,{a function},{some parameters})

See: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html

So try...
telecom_final_Analyse%>%mutate_if(is.numeric, ntile, 10)

Note this will.mutate the existing columns.  If you want to keep the old ones and create new ones you can wrap multiple mutate functions in  "list(first_function, second_function)" and then the output data set will be wider than before.  It's all there in the online help.
Hope this works for you